# HttpCookieCollection.Get(): Possible NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, resharper

I see the ReSharper warning 'Possible NullReferenceException' on this code on second line:

```
var cookie = HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies[CookieName];
cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
```

I checked HttpCookieCollection.Get() Method in MSDN and it says *'If the named cookie does not exist, this method creates a new cookie with that name.'*. So it looks like NullReferenceException can't happen.

Is it just ReSharper bug or I missed something?

Answer (score 2):

> So it looks like NullReferenceException can't happen.

`HttpContext.Current` will be null if you execute this code outside of an ASP.NET context, like for example unit test, console or desktop application.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Need to clarify, warning appears on second line. I updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

HttpCookieCollection.Get() can cause a null reference exception when it is not called from HttpResponse.  So, ReSharper is technically correct that an exception could occur, although it will not happen in your code example.  [This so question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16401343/65704) shows an example where the null refence is possible.